# Working with multiple APIs for Multi-platform apps

Tags: api, browser-extension

I currently have a Chrome extension that uses Chrome's APIs and plan on making a Microsoft Edge version once it opens up as well. My question is how do you work with the multiple API's?

For example, I use the following to check if the extension has just been installed or not:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled
```

I'm assuming for Edge it would be something like:

```
edge.runtime.onInstalled
```

What's the best way to work with both of these? Do I just duplicate the code within the file where there is a copy of the code for one and the other and presumably the browser will ignore the other browser's code? (doesn't sound like the good option)

Or is there some cross-browser framework that I should use instead?

Or is there some other solution?

And please forgive me, this is my first entry into building extensions/apps, I'm generally just a Web Designer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers support or

`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`

or

`browser.runtime.onInstalled`

So, the right way is to start scripts in your extension with this code:

`var browser = browser || chrome`

And then use `browser`, for example:

`browser.runtime.onInstalled`

(I'm sorry about my english)

Edit:

Chrome and Opera support `chrome` and not `browser`.

Firefox support `chrome` and `browser`.

Edge support `browser` and I don't know if it support `chrome`.

Anyway, my solution work in all browsers.

**Update (5.8.16):**

Edge support `browser` and not `chrome`.